# Eliminate duplicate field combinations

Tags: mysql

I want to eliminate duplicate field1/field2 combinations in my DB. My pseudo query below:

```
 SELECT * WHERE DISTINCT field1 AND field2
```

The table with duplicates is below:

```
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| id  | field1 | field2 | field3 |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1  |   A    |   B    |   Z    |
|  2  |   A    |   B    |   Q    |
|  3  |   A    |   C    |   K    |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to eliminate rows with duplicate field1/field2 combinations. Row 2 was dropped b/c it was a duplicate of row 1.

```
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| id  | field1 | field2 | field3 |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1  |   A    |   B    |   Z    |
|  3  |   A    |   C    |   K    |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Regarding to how you chose which record to return for duplicates (id 1 instead of id 2), what are the criteria?

Comment: I want to eliminate duplicate rows where both field1 and field2 are duplicates.

Comment: But how do you chose Z from Z and Q in field3?  max value?

Comment: The selection criteria is based on field1 and field 2. Field 3 has all unique values.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you this way, "Why did you discard the record with id 2 in favor of the record with id 1?"

Comment: it was dropped b/c both row 1 and row 2 had matching values in field1 and field2.

Comment: Yes, how/why did you decide to throw away 'Q' in favour of 'Z' for id=2? Also are the id values significant or can they be re-generated in a new table?

Comment: @Enki Then why you didn't discard the one with id 1 in favor of the one with id 2?  Any logic?

Comment: the values Q and Z are not part of the selection criteria.

Comment: @Enki - you're driving me insane reading this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This select will narrow your results as you want:

```
select id, field1, field2, field3 from testtable1 group by field1,field2;
```

So this will create a new table with the duplicates eliminated:

```
create table testtable2 select id, field1, field2, field3 from testtable1 group by field1,field2;
```

Replace `testtable1` with the appropriate name of your existing table.

Comment: Yes, perfect, it'll arbitrarily choose which row(s) to eliminate rather than applying valid business logic!

Comment: From the comments above, apparently he doesn't care :)